# Android Networking with HttpClient takes a lot of time

Tags: android, http, android-networking

I'm having problem when I try to use HttpCleitn to fetch data from my server it takes a lot of time (about 30sec and response is only a few kB) and it keeps logging a messages: "Skippe xxx frames. App may be doing too much work on its main thread". There just a plenty of these messages (like a 1000 or 2000).
I'm really new to android dev and have no idea what i'm doing wrong. Though all the process of fetching data from the server is held inside the doInBackground method.

Here's all my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView videoList;
ArrayList<String> videoArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> videoAdapter;
Context context;
String feedUrl = "http://www.rateksib.ru/ios/track_json.php?order=НскС101712124";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    videoArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    videoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videoList);
    videoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.video_list_item, videoArrayList);
    videoList.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

    VideoListTask loaderTask = new VideoListTask();
    loaderTask.execute();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class VideoListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Выполняется запрос");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(feedUrl);

        try 
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if( statusLine.getStatusCode() != 200 ) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            String jsonData = stringBuilder.toString();

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results");

            for( int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++ ) {
                JSONObject item = results.getJSONObject(i);

                String status = item.getString("status");
                String date = item.getString("date");

                Log.i("OK:", "Detsya");

                videoArrayList.add(date + ": " + status);
            }



        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: this is related to network connection speed, did your activity freeze?

Comment: No, it keeps going and actually shows me results of the request. But like I said, it takes a lot of time. I don't think that's the network connection speed issue because similar app for iphone works instantly

Comment: this issue is cased by internet connectivity. It may be slow

Comment: Better you check the url (type the url) in the web browser of the device (which you testing.).Then find whether network slow or any other

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J I followed your suggestion and it worked perfrctly fine and fast in the browser.

Comment: I thinkk in your code the data is receiving is correct sppeed.But you using for loop in your code.The for loop only delays.In your app data is received is in correct speed.But the processing of data is have delay due to for loop.So try to reduce the for loop iteration or try any other logic to reduce the processing time

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J you know, the result data set is so small that it can't exceed 4 iterations in for loop. do you think it can still cause the ussie? Personally I think that the problem is in that enormous amount of messages in logCat about skipped frames and i don't know how to get rid of them